# Conditional rolling sum of events with 'ragged' dates

Tags: r, rolling-sum

## Introduction

I am using R to analyze the 'momentum' of protest movements in Africa. To do so, I am analyzing individual protest events. I want to create a rolling measure of the **rolling number (sum) of protests within a time period**.

Most of the answers here on Stack Overflow deal with datasets where observations are at fixed intervals (one obs. per day or per month, etc.). But my data are 'ragged' in the sense that they occur in different intervals. Sometimes there is one day between observations. Other times there are two weeks.

### What I want to create

A rolling sum of the number of protest events that have occurred in a given country over the past 10 days. This would be in the form of a variable that simply sums the number of events within the past ten days, inclusive of the current event.

### The Data

Here is a reproducible set of data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("8/1/2019", "8/2/2019", "8/3/2019", "8/6/2019", "8/15/2019", "8/16/2019", "8/30/2019", "9/1/2019", "9/2/2019", "9/3/2019", "9/4/2019", "6/1/2019", "6/26/2019", "7/1/2019", "7/2/2019", "7/9/2019", "7/10/2019", "8/1/2019", "8/2/2019", "8/15/2019", "8/28/2019", "9/1/2019"),
country = c(rep("Algeria", 11), rep("Benin", 11)),
event = rep("Protest", 22))
```

### What I want the data to look like

```
date       country   event     roll_sum
--------   -------   -------   --------
8/1/2019   Algeria   Protest   1
8/2/2019   Algeria   Protest   2
8/3/2019   Algeria   Protest   3
8/6/2019   Algeria   Protest   4
8/15/2019  Algeria   Protest   2
8/16/2019  Algeria   Protest   3
8/30/2019  Algeria   Protest   1
9/1/2019   Algeria   Protest   2
9/2/2019   Algeria   Protest   3
9/3/2019   Algeria   Protest   4 
9/4/2019   Algeria   Protest   5
6/1/2019   Benin     Protest   1
6/26/2019  Benin     Protest   1
7/1/2019   Benin     Protest   2
7/2/2019   Benin     Protest   3
7/9/2019   Benin     Protest   3
7/10/2019  Benin     Protest   4
8/1/2019   Benin     Protest   1
8/2/2019   Benin     Protest   2
8/15/2019  Benin     Protest   1
8/28/2019  Benin     Protest   1
9/1/2019   Benin     Protest   2
```

This is all probably very simple, but I can't figure out how to do it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base R` approach,

```
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date,"%m/%d/%Y")

vector <- vector()

for( j in unique(df1$country)) {
    df2 <- df1[df1$country==j,]
    for(i in 1:nrow(df2)) {

     k <- nrow(df2[df2$date<= df2$date[i] & df2$date>=df2$date[i]-10 ,])

     vector <- c(vector, k)

    }
}

df1$roll_sum <- vector
```

gives,

```
         date country   event roll_sum
1  2019-08-01 Algeria Protest        1
2  2019-08-02 Algeria Protest        2
3  2019-08-03 Algeria Protest        3
4  2019-08-06 Algeria Protest        4
5  2019-08-15 Algeria Protest        2
6  2019-08-16 Algeria Protest        3
7  2019-08-30 Algeria Protest        1
8  2019-09-01 Algeria Protest        2
9  2019-09-02 Algeria Protest        3
10 2019-09-03 Algeria Protest        4
11 2019-09-04 Algeria Protest        5
12 2019-06-01   Benin Protest        1
13 2019-06-26   Benin Protest        1
14 2019-07-01   Benin Protest        2
15 2019-07-02   Benin Protest        3
16 2019-07-09   Benin Protest        3
17 2019-07-10   Benin Protest        4
18 2019-08-01   Benin Protest        1
19 2019-08-02   Benin Protest        2
20 2019-08-15   Benin Protest        1
21 2019-08-28   Benin Protest        1
22 2019-09-01   Benin Protest        2
```

Answer (score 4):

use `lubridate` to convert date string into `date` and create intervals using `interval` function. `%within%` is a function in `lubridate` which returns whether the given date vector is within the interval.

Create a `dates` column which on each row is a list that stores all dates for that country. And use `purrr::pmap()` to iterate all rows in the modified data frame.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("8/1/2019", "8/2/2019", "8/3/2019", "8/6/2019", "8/15/2019", "8/16/2019", "8/30/2019", "9/1/2019", "9/2/2019", "9/3/2019", "9/4/2019", "6/1/2019", "6/26/2019", "7/1/2019", "7/2/2019", "7/9/2019", "7/10/2019", "8/1/2019", "8/2/2019", "8/15/2019", "8/28/2019", "9/1/2019"),
                  country = c(rep("Algeria", 11), rep("Benin", 11)),
                  event = rep("Protest", 22))

df2 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(
        date = mdy(date),
        interval = interval(date -days(10),date)
    ) %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    mutate(dates = list(date)) %>%
    ungroup()

df2["roll_sum"] <- pmap_dbl(df2,function(...){
    values <- list(...)
    sum(values$dates %within% values$interval)
}) 
df2 %>%
    select(-interval,-dates)
```

```r
# A tibble: 22 x 4
   date       country event   roll_sum
   <date>     <fct>   <fct>      <dbl>
 1 2019-08-01 Algeria Protest        1
 2 2019-08-02 Algeria Protest        2
 3 2019-08-03 Algeria Protest        3
 4 2019-08-06 Algeria Protest        4
 5 2019-08-15 Algeria Protest        2
 6 2019-08-16 Algeria Protest        3
 7 2019-08-30 Algeria Protest        1
 8 2019-09-01 Algeria Protest        2
 9 2019-09-02 Algeria Protest        3
10 2019-09-03 Algeria Protest        4
# ... with 12 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

`rollapply` in zoo takes a width argument which can be a vector in case each point has a different width.  To compute that width `w` we convert `date` to `Date` class and then use `ave` to compute for each country the widths via `wfun` which uses `findInterval` to find the position of the most recent date no later than 11 days ago.  If we subtract that position from the current position it will give us the desired width.  Finally we run `rollapplyr`.

In the question all events shown were `Protest` and if that were always the case then the rolling sum would equal `w` so we could avoid the rolling computation in the last line of code; however, we did not make such simplification in case your full data set includes other types of event that should not be counted.

```
library(zoo)

df2 <- transform(df1, date = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y"))

wfun <- function(x) seq_along(x) - findInterval(x - 11, x)
w <- with(df2, ave(as.numeric(date), country, FUN = wfun))
transform(df2, roll_sum = rollapplyr(event == "Protest", w, sum))
```

giving (continued after output):

```
         date country   event roll_sum
1  2019-08-01 Algeria Protest        1
2  2019-08-02 Algeria Protest        2
3  2019-08-03 Algeria Protest        3
4  2019-08-06 Algeria Protest        4
5  2019-08-15 Algeria Protest        2
6  2019-08-16 Algeria Protest        3
7  2019-08-30 Algeria Protest        1
8  2019-09-01 Algeria Protest        2
9  2019-09-02 Algeria Protest        3
10 2019-09-03 Algeria Protest        4
11 2019-09-04 Algeria Protest        5
12 2019-06-01   Benin Protest        1
13 2019-06-26   Benin Protest        1
14 2019-07-01   Benin Protest        2
15 2019-07-02   Benin Protest        3
16 2019-07-09   Benin Protest        3
17 2019-07-10   Benin Protest        4
18 2019-08-01   Benin Protest        1
19 2019-08-02   Benin Protest        2
20 2019-08-15   Benin Protest        1
21 2019-08-28   Benin Protest        1
22 2019-09-01   Benin Protest        2
```

### Note

We can double check `w` using a second approach to calculate `w`.  This involves scanning all of `date` for each element of the width vector so using the following approach is rather inefficient compared to the `findInterval` approach shown above but just as a double check that should not matter.

```
wfun2 <- function(x) sapply(x, function(y) sum(x >= y-10 & x <= y))
w2 <- with(df2, ave(as.numeric(date), country, FUN = wfun2))

identical(w, w2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `dplyr` and `purrr::map_int`. We can `group_by` `country` and find out number of rows in the dataset in past 10 days from current `date`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(roll_sum = purrr::map_int(date, ~sum(date >= (.x - 10) & date <= (.x))))

#    date       country event   roll_sum
#   <date>     <fct>   <fct>      <int>
# 1 2019-08-01 Algeria Protest        1
# 2 2019-08-02 Algeria Protest        2
# 3 2019-08-03 Algeria Protest        3
# 4 2019-08-06 Algeria Protest        4
# 5 2019-08-15 Algeria Protest        2
# 6 2019-08-16 Algeria Protest        3
# 7 2019-08-30 Algeria Protest        1
# 8 2019-09-01 Algeria Protest        2
# 9 2019-09-02 Algeria Protest        3
#10 2019-09-03 Algeria Protest        4
# … with 12 more rows
```